# REST: update a resource with different fields requiring different user permissions

Tags: rest, http

I have an endpoint `/groups`

I can create a group by POSTing some info to `/groups`

A single group can be read by `/groups/{id}`

I can update some fields in the group by POSTing to `/group/{id}`

HOWEVER I have different fields that are needed to be updated by users with different permissions, for instance: A group might have the structure

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "some name",
 "members": [
  {
   "user_id": 456,
   "known_as": "Name 1",
   "user": { /* some user object */},
   "status": "accepted",
   "role": "admin",
   "shared": "something"
  },
  {
   "user_id": 999227,
   "known_as": "Name 1",
   "user": { /* some user object */},
   "status": "accepted",
   "role": "basic",
   "shared": "something"
  },
  {
   "user_id": 9883,
   "known_as": "Name 1",
   "user": { /* some user object */},
   "status": "requested",
   "role": "basic",
   "shared": "something"
  }
 ],
 "link": "https://some-link"
}
```

As an example I have the following 3 operations for the `/group/{id}/members/{id}` endpoint:

- I want only the user to be able to update his own `known_as` field
- I want only group admins to be able to update each member's `role` and `status` fields.
- I want both the user and the admin to be able to update the `shared` field

My options are this:

1. Should I allow all updates to be done by POSTing to `/group/{id}/members/{id}` with a subset of the fields for a member and throw an unauthorized error if they try to update a field that they aren't allowed to update?
2. Or should I break each operation into say `/group/{id}/members/{id}/role`, `/group/{id}/members/{id}/shared` and `/group/{id}/members/{id}/status`? The problem with this is that I don't want to have to make lots of requests to update all the fields (I imagine that there will end up being quite a lot of them).

So just for clarification my question is: Is it considered proper REST to do my **option 1** where I can post updates to an endpoint that may fail if you try to change a field that you aren't allowed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, option 1 is much better than option 2.

As you said option 2 is a waste of bandwidth.

More importantly, with option 1 you can easily implement an atomic update (update "all-or-nothing"). It should either complete successfully or fail entirely. There should never be a partial update.

With option 2 it's very likely the update can be implemented to complete some request successfully and reject another request, even if the two requests are considered a single operation.